# WebStorm to recognize Protractor config options

Tags: javascript, protractor, webstorm

If we open our Protractor config in WebStorm, it would highlight multiple things in gray, as "unused", which makes me think it just does not recognize the options. For instance, `getMultiCapabilities` and `onCleanUp` are not recognized:

[image]
[image]

On the other hand, options like `onPrepare`, `baseUrl`, `framework` are recognized by WebStorm.

Among other libraries, I have `angular-protractor-DefinitelyTyped` configured.

`onCleanUp()`, for instance, was introduced [long ago](https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/088a58150f992a6520da983fc461fec4eac1a0ed), in Protractor 0.17.0, which makes me think it's not about an outdated libraries.

**The Question:**

How to make WebStorm understand all of the Protractor configuration options?

<sup>Let me know if you would need any additional information.</sup>

Comment: Had you set up Protractor as a running environment in Webstorm, i.e. so you can start "Run" or "Debug" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, it's not possible to teach WebStorm understand things like `onCleanUp` since it's not ["directly" defined inside Protractor itself](https://github.com/angular/protractor/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=onCleanUp&type=Code).